# POST JSON with curl and access token. Getting: Illegally formatted input field! error. Ads API

Tags: php, json, post, curl

I'm very new to curl and totally confused. My code so far is that:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json'\
  -F 'name=My new CA' \
  -F 'subtype=CUSTOM' \
  -F 'description=People who bought from my website' \
  -F -d 'rule': {'and': ['or': [{'unit_id': {'gte': '0'}}]]}\
  -F 'access_token=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA' \
  https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/act_XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/customaudiences
```

I can't figure out how to post that nested request and I get the following error:

```
Warning: Illegally formatted input field!
curl: option -F: is badly used here
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

Any suggestions are appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Look at what you're sending:

```
-F -d 'rule': {'and': ['or': [{'unit_id': {'gte': '0'}}]]}\
      ^--start string
           ^--end string
            ^--random garbage
               ^--start another string
                   ^--end string
```

Comment: I figured out that I need escaping slashes \ and enclosing braces "{  }" around the rule line.
I also cannot mix -F and -d.
Thank you!